# HEROKU: how to delete asset file from server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I attached the file by Paperclip and then destroyed it like an object, but the asset file remains on the server.
How to delete this file?

Comment: what stack? It must be Cedar if you've uploaded to Heroku

Comment: I mean 'asset' in kind of attachment. I just uploaded audio-file and it was saved to public/assets directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling destroy on the file should delete it - `@mymodel.myfile.destroy` - although you would be **MUCH** better advised to use Amazon S3 to host your assets. Anything you upload into your app  n Heroku that lives in tmp, public etc will not exist across dynos, or persist across restarts unless you're using an external storage host like Amazon S3 etc.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem talks about it in detail.